# Быстрое сложение изображений в C#

Tags: c#, gpu, emgucv, emgu

**Основная задача:** мне необходимо в реальном времени (или около того) сложение двух Grayscale FullHD 8bit изображений (которые будут использованы как R и G каналы)  с камеры (60fps, производитель Imaging Source) в одно FullHD 24bit изображение (R,G,coef*G). Необходимо все полученные изображения отображать на экране (в виде realtime трансляции). Язык разработки - c#. Ограничение на coef: 0 < coef < 1.

Заступорился на создании самой функции быстрого сложения. Необходима "очень быстрая" отработка. Подразумеваю "<=0.01с на получение результирующего изображения".

**Попытка формулировки вопроса:**
 Какой специфический алгоритм обработки нужно использовать, чтобы решить подобную задачу, а именно проблему скорости? Через указатели я добился отработки примерно в 0.05с, что все еще долго.Буду рад полезным ссылкам (примеры, обучалки и прочее).
Функция, которой произвожу обработку:

```
    private unsafe Bitmap Create_RGB_BMP_FastUnsafe(Bitmap pBMP1, Bitmap pBMP2, bool GreenFirst)
    {
        int width = 1920;
        int height = 1080;
        int WH = width * height;
        var pRes = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        BitmapData bd_red, bd_green, bd_res;
        if (GreenFirst)
        {
            bd_green = pBMP1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            bd_red = pBMP2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            bd_res = pRes.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
               PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);//greenfirst=true;
        }
        else
        {
            bd_red = pBMP1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            bd_green = pBMP2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            bd_res = pRes.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
               PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);//greenfirst=false;
        }
        try
        {
            int stride1 = bd_red.Stride;
            int sk;
            byte* curpos_red = (byte*)bd_red.Scan0;
            byte* curpos_green = (byte*)bd_green.Scan0;
            byte* _currentPX = (byte*)bd_res.Scan0;
            for (sk = 0; sk < WH; sk++)
            {
                *_currentPX = (byte)(*(curpos_green) * 0.1); ++_currentPX;
                *_currentPX = *(curpos_green++); ++_currentPX;
                *_currentPX = *(curpos_red++); ++_currentPX;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            pBMP1.UnlockBits(bd_red);
            pBMP2.UnlockBits(bd_green);
            pRes.UnlockBits(bd_res);
        }
        return pRes;
    }
```

**P.S.:** Кое-что из того, что я уже прочитал, перед тем, как спросить у вас, профессионалы)...

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687637/fastest-image-processing-library
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101986/iterate-over-pixels-of-an-image-with-emgu-cv/5107490#5107490
3. https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/newprolab/blog/328422/
4. https://m.habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/256533/
5. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33838/Image-Processing-using-C

Comment: Зачем писать, столько воды, когда можно было просто дать код и написать вопрос, что необходимо сделать. Без кодов, вам вряд ли кто-то поможет.

Comment: @And зачем, что не любой вопрос украшает код. Код, который не имеет отношения к вопросу, лишь помогает собирать минусы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, прочитайте внимательно вопрос, он уже пытался решить и у него вышло, `а где- это вышло?`

Comment: Окей, приложу версию кода, который справляется с задачей за 0.05 секунды. Однако, смогу это сделать только вечером, часов в 19.00 по МСК

Comment: Судя по тэгам, opencv в каком-то виде задействовали? Замечу, что требуется скорость обработки 1.2 гигабайта в секунду, что немало. но реально.

Comment: @MBo, спасибо за заметку. Дело в том, что в первоначальном виде в вопросе было предположение о том, что НУЖНО использовать openCV (я его пока не юзаю). Собственно, c GPU дело обстоит так же. Приложил код, в котором добился отработки за 0,05с

Comment: Зачем вы постоянно создаете новые объекты Bitmap на каждый кадр? Вообще, в таких часто вызываемых местах желательно вовсе не создавать новых объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Что замедляет работу кода (что-то может быть не очень актуально, т.к. я не знаю точно, какой код генерирует шарп):

Необязательное здесь использование вещественной арифметики. Можно масштабировать коэффициент и после целочисленного умножения на него делить на 256 (возможно, нужно приводить к int для корректного умножения и потом к байту)

```
 cf256 = (int) 256 * coeff
 *_currentPX = (*(curpos_green) * сf256 >> 8); ++_currentPX;
```

Прыжки по памяти в три разных места - от этого полностью не избавиться, но в  развертывание циклов может в какой-то мере помочь (возможно, кодогенератор сам умеет это делать, как некоторые плюсовые компиляторы в режиме суровой оптимизации)

Задача числомолотильная отлично подходит для MMX/SSE2/AVX2 блоков процессора. При этом несколько пикселов (сколько выходных пикселов влезет в 8/16/32 байта регистра SIMD) обрабатываются одновременно - при лобовом использовании можно ожидать ускорения раза в 4 (для SSE2). Можно ли это использовать в шарпе? Генерируется ли код для SIMD обработки?

(При использовании SIMD отказываться от float арифметики не обязательно)

Собственно, перечисленное реализовано опытными людьми в OpenCV, поэтому при возможности стоит эту библиотеку использовать.

Есть еще вариант, если это будет единственная вычислительно тяжелая  задача - написать функцию на C/C++ с использованием SIMD инструкций (интринсики или вообще компилятор обеспечит автоматическую векторизацию) и вызывать её из C# (вероятно, нужно будет делать DLL).

И напоследок - если обработка 60 кадров в секунду нужна только для отображения - не разумно ли ограничиться обработкой и выводом 30 кадров?

Comment: Благодарю за дельные советы. Совет про масштабирование коэффициентов хорош.
По поводу отображения: дело в том, что это только первый этап работы. На втором этапе по двум результирующим изображениям будет формироваться HDR, и поэтому нужно 60 кадров сейчас.

_"Можно ли это использовать в шарпе? Генерируется ли код для SIMD обработки?"_
Я, по неопытности, пока даже не понимаю, о чем речь. Достаточно ли сказать, что я использую Visual studio 2015? Не уверен. 

Про openCV понял, однако, когда я реализовывал подобную задачу, у меня плохо отрабатывал сборщик мусора (память забивалась до 4гб)

Comment: Попробовал масштабирование коэффициента с последующим сдвигом. 0.033с, уже лучше. Что ж, пора идти в openCV? И сразу второй вопрос: принципиально все делать так же? Насколько я помню, там такое-же обращение к указателям и прочее...

Comment: В OpenCV есть свои классы, основная рабочая единица  - Mat (оно же IPLImage). Создаются 8-битные монохромные матрицы нужной размерности, в них принимаются данные (при приеме с камеры создание автоматическое), проводится умножение одной на коэффициент и merge https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge  ( в emgucv, видимо, вот оно: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/9d277ff9-9f12-1912-3a54-98cbc3e401e6.htm )

Comment: Хорошо. Ночью буду пробовать, отпишусь как только, так сразу! А пока спасибо)

Comment: Добавил пункт про C/C++, если OpenCV не пойдёт

Comment: Пока что только настроил OpenCV, пробы будут уже сегодня вечером, видимо. Отпишусь здесь позже.